# LIKE autocompletion too stressful on the database?

Tags: android, mysql, sql, database, autocomplete

I'm writing an android application that has a search feature that needs to autocomplete from a list of stores. This list will only have up to a few thousand stores in it.

My current methodology is to send a LIKE query to the database every few hundred ms after the user has stopped typing and to populate the autocomplete list with these results.

Would using this method be stressful to the database?

It has been suggested to me that this wouldn't work because making continuous calls would be poor for users with a slow connection and that I should load all the stores into memory and filter from there.

Comment: Instead of like, a substring would work.  where left(field,3) = 'ABC' will work better than where field like 'ABC%'.   I suspect you'd want to store in local memory anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At my work I ran into a similar problem a few months back.  The contents of a text box filled by the user were supposed to filter their available options to choose from in a list of strings.  The list needed to be updated every time the user typed a key so database calls to fetch records that matched their text were being made several times a second.

This ended up being wayy to slow to update as someone was typing, and this was only with several thousand records and with a server that was being accessed on site.

If you want to update as quickly as someone can type, making that many database calls simply won't do.  Users will get pretty antsy having to let their phone buffer to type in some text.

**In Short:**  Make one databse call and load it up onto the phone,  and run your filter algorithm from there.

Answer (score 0):

Regularly syncing the list of stores from your back end to the user's device and implementing autocomplete locally is the best way to go.

The [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) API provides a flexible way to set constraints on your background syncing processes.